# Renderscript intrinsics for trigonometric functions

Tags: android, trigonometry, renderscript, intrinsics

On developer.android.com there are basic functions to do multiplications and additions for each element on arrays like:

```
void    forEachDstOver(Allocation ain, Allocation aout, Script.LaunchOptions opt)
Sets dst = dst + src * (1.0 - dst.a)
void    forEachMultiply(Allocation ain, Allocation aout)
Sets dst = src * dst
void    forEachMultiply(Allocation ain, Allocation aout, Script.LaunchOptions opt)
Sets dst = src * dst
```

But I couldnt find trigonometric functions. Im porting some of my opencl codes to android and in a n-body benchmark, I need to do inverse square root fast. I assume this function has better compute to data ratio and should have been written somewhere but I couldnt find. For now,  renderscript version(75 - 85 ms) without intrinsics gives nearly 5x performance of serial java code(350-400 ms) for 4096 particles using bruteforce.

How do I make a new renderscript intrinsic that uses GPU,CPU,DSP ?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/reference/rs_math.html#android_rs:half_rsqrt

Comment: Itried that, did not work with #pragma rs_fp_relaxed and crashed the application.

Comment: I think this question is somewhat misguided. Intrinsics are a fixed set of functions, so you cannot create a new one with your custom processing. You will have to write your own Renderscript code for that, which I take you already did and for some reason are unhappy with? Otherwise, why exactly do you want to use intrinsics?

Comment: Im thinking of going augmented reality, fluid simulators, object movement detection, .... but I dont even know the basics of android fully. In desktop, even single threaded version of SIMD code increases performance by at least 3 times. Maybe desktop cpu are not as efficient per core as SoC in android? Maybe there is no such room in mobile to go 100x performance of serial-scalar version as in desktop?

Comment: 100x is unlikely, but it's difficult to say more without seeing your code. Will you be posting it?